# Issue with Message Handler

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using Messages and handlers to change the message of a processdialog that shows while executing a thread. The code is given below.

```
final ProgressDialog processdialog = ProgressDialog
        .show(MultiBootManager.this, EMPTY,
                EMPTY, true);
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.arg1) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("msg0");
            processdialog
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.formating)
                            + folderpath
                            + getString(R.string.cachext3));
        case 1:
            System.out.println("msg1");
            processdialog
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.formating)
                            + folderpath
                            + getString(R.string.dataext3));
        case 2:
            System.out.println("msg2");
            processdialog
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.formating)
                            + folderpath
                            + getString(R.string.systemext3));
        case 3:
            System.out.println("endmsg");
            processdialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
};
Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String[] shellinput = { EMPTY,
                EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY };
        shellinput[0] = CMD_MKE2FS_EXT3;
        shellinput[1] = folderpath;
        if (cacheCheckBool) {
            final Message m0 = new Message();
            m0.arg1 = 0;
            handler.sendMessage(m0);
            shellinput[2] = CACHE_IMG;
            processManager
                    .inputStreamReader(
                            shellinput, 20);
        }
        if (dataCheckBool) {
            final Message m1 = new Message();
            m1.arg1 = 1;
            handler.sendMessage(m1);
            shellinput[2] = DATA_IMG;
            processManager
                    .inputStreamReader(
                            shellinput, 20);
        }
        final Message endmessage;
        if (systemCheckBool) {
            final Message m2 = new Message();
            m2.arg1 = 2;
            handler.sendMessage(m2);
            shellinput[2] = DATA_IMG;
            processManager
                    .inputStreamReader(
                            shellinput, 20);
        }
        endmessage = new Message();
        endmessage.arg1 = 3;
        handler.sendMessage(endmessage);
    }
};
checkUpdate.start();
```

}

The problem I'm experiencing now is that the `endmessage` is sent before completion of the operation, the `ProcessDialog` closes in like 0.5 sec. If all the `Boolean` are true it shows `msg1, msg2, msg3, emdmsg` rapidly in `System.out` and closes. Why this behavior? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add breaks to each case. Otherwise, execution will fall through to the next case.

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.arg1) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("msg0");
        processdialog
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.formating)
                        + folderpath
                        + getString(R.string.cachext3));
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("msg1");
        processdialog
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.formating)
                        + folderpath
                        + getString(R.string.dataext3));
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("msg2");
        processdialog
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.formating)
                        + folderpath
                        + getString(R.string.systemext3));
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("endmsg");
        processdialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }
```

The last break is not strictly needed, but it's a good habit to always end them with a break, so that if you later add a new case, you don't have to remember to add a break to the previous case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand - but your code just "fires" `sendMessages` without any order really. So in particular it runs through each if statemment, fires the associated message and then - no matter what happens with these messages or anywhere else, it reaches `handler.sendMessage(endmessage);`
 and justz fires this too.

Nowwhere I see a "gatekeeper" that checks when exactly to send your endMsg.

Is this your question?